# How to use Sharepoint URL without port number - Alternative URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping

if  have a site url address : http://intranet.domainname.com:9999

How can i also use this url address:

http://intranet.domainname.com

without the port number

Do i have to use Alternate Access Mapping for this or just change the host header?

I would also want SharePoint to know about this and resolve it correctly.
So that i won't have issue with url to documents or lists moving forward

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

however if this application already exists you can do one of the following:

1. Extend the web app and give this extended web app a url of intranet.domainname.com and host header with the same value. Choose port 80 as the port. I believe this is the best way. [Read more here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261698.aspx)
2. As a quick fix you can create an empty web application with the address http://intranet.domain.com on port 80 and a host header which only redirects to your 9999 site. All this does is redirect... Users will see the port number after the redirection.
3. Delete the web app without deleting the content db and create a new web app and reattatch the content db.

Again the first is the one I would recommend going with. Let me know if you have any questions about these. Hope it helps!

Comment: You should not extend the web app to fix a prior configuration mistake.  It is pretty easy to just re-provision the web app and attach your existing content to it.

Comment: Thanks Mike and Onzur.
This instance hasn't been configured.So basically i just want to make sure to plan to achieve a url with no port name.

Answer (score 3):

If the web application is set to use a specific port, you will be bound to that port even with a host header.  So simply put, if you want to have http://intranet.domainname.com then you have to have the web application available on port 80.

Using host headers you can have lots of unique names available on the same server, so there really is no reason not to put SharePoint on port 80 for regular web applications.

Comment: Thanks Mike.
I would also be having other custom apps on that IIS and would prefer to use port 80 for them.
I wouldn't like to risk to have sharepoint and other custom apps running on the same port.

Comment: @naijacoder If the custom apps are running in their own app pool, they will have isolated application space and memory so sharing a port will for a given IP still will not matter.